# order of $ln(1+\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$

Tags: asymptotics

I am struggling with understanding how to find the order of this expression. The answer in the solutions is $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}= \frac{ln(1+\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$. I don't understand the concept of putting $\epsilon$ in the denominator

Comment: Fix the typo in your equation, this is meaningless.

Comment: Since $\ln(1) = 0$, this is the same as $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \frac{\ln(1+\epsilon) - \ln(1)}{\epsilon}$. Does this remind you of something?

Comment: Usually the order of $f(x)$ as $x \to 0$ means the largest real number $a$ such that $\frac{f(x)}{x^a}$ remains bounded as $x \to 0$. That's more or less just the definition, though if you have an actual definition in hand then that's helpful to us for explaining things. In any case, do you see why it makes some sense to guess that the order might be $1$ here?

Comment: I believe I have to use the Gauge function which is defined as $g(\epsilon)$ and is used in the context  $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{f(\epsilon)}{g(\epsilon)}=A$ where A is a non-zero constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us use this definition:

$$\log(1+\epsilon)=\int_1^{1+\epsilon}\dfrac{dt}t.$$

Then as the inverse is a monotonous function,

$$\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}=\int_1^{1+\epsilon}\dfrac{dt}{1+\epsilon}<\log(1+\epsilon)<\int_1^{1+\epsilon} dt=\epsilon.$$

---

[image]